# Why do the media work on the phone screen?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

The resolution of my phone is 2280x1080. Why does the following code change the background color to blue on my phone?

```
@media (max-width: 500px) { body { background-color: blue; } }
```

Interestingly, it stops working after turning on "computer mode".
Confirmed for chrome and firefox preview.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this topic is kinda broad from my perspective, but I can give you an overall answer.

Firstly, I strongly think that you wanted to say 1080x2280. It's misleading if you're not specifying the **width first**.

The resolution of your phone is expressed as number of physical pixels. The values used by CSS are actually something known as logical pixels. Logical pixels represent basically the physical pixels, divided by your device DPR(Device Pixel Ratio).

Therefore, the [Viewport](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Viewport) of your browser will have a dimension of 360x760, if you own a device like Samsung Galaxy S10, which has a DPR of 4.

Great video on this topic: [Pixel Density, Demystified](https://vimeo.com/169809377)

Physical Pixels vs. Logical: https://blog.specctr.com/pixels-physical-vs-logical-c84710199d62

Comment: Thank you. If I understand the formula correctly: logical pixels = physical pixels / DPR? For example: 1080 / 4 = 270 (if DPR=4)?Sorry for 2280x1080.Samsung should correct this in the settings.

Comment: Yep, you're right. Here is a [useful resource](https://material.io/resources/devices/) with other examples. `Width x Height dp`(dp from _Device-independent Pixel_) represents those logical pixels, while **Width x Height px** are the physical pixels and **Density** is the DPR.

Answer (score 0):

If your phones is 1080 pixels wide, that the `device-width` - the physical pixels on the screen. If its `device-pixel-ratio` of that phone is for example `3`, this means that every "css pixel" equals 3x3 device pixels. `max-width: 500px` in a media query refers to the "css pixels", so, with a device-pixel-ratio of 3 that would be 1500 device pixels. And your phone would have a screen size of 760x360 (css) pixels.

The big advantage of a high device-pixel-ratio (retina display and similar) is that vector graphics, fonts and high-resolution images will be displayed with much more detail / better resolution. But the pixel unit in CSS rules still refers to the "css pixels", which is why your background is blue / that media query is applied.

You *can* also use `min-device-width` / `max-device-width` in media queries. However, for most purposes it's better to use `max-width`/ `min-width` and think in / work with "css pixels"

P.S.: The "computer mode" you are talking about most likely deactivates or changes the settings in the `viewport` meta tag.

Answer (score -1):

You also have to type `screen` after the word media to check for the screen media queries can check more than just screens 
W3C Source: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

So in your case it will be :

```
@media screen and (max-width: 500px){ body { background-color: blue; } }
```

Comment: Still works for `@media screen and (max-width: 500px)` (in chrome)

Comment: Definitely not.  It still works (and it shouldn't!)

Comment: Take a look at this, you can choose what device:https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/